# How to place two spans side by side and then one span on top of them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to place two spans side by side, and then one span on top and to the left. Something like below where each price is a span. I am absolutely terrible at CSS so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
$1.15
$2.00 $3.00
```

I currently have the following HTML but it has everything side by side.

```
<span id="top-left" class="is-text-align-right">$1.15</span>
<span id="bottom-left" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$2.00</span>
<span id="bottom-right" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$3.00</span>
```

Comment: Show the HTML related to your question. It is encouraged to try and show your attempt so we can give you notes and direction on how to solve your issue.

Comment: Take a look at flexbox and/or css grid. both are great options for this type of problem!

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll edit my post with the HTML.

Comment: by default span will not break the line

Comment: you can add it <br> after span or you can write it with css

Answer (score 1):

```
#top-left {display: block}
or
span.is-text-align-right:fisrt-child(display:block)
```

```css
#top-left {display: block;}
```

```html
<span id="top-left" class="is-text-align-right">$1.15</span>
<span id="bottom-left" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$2.00</span>
<span id="bottom-right" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$3.00</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a little solution usinf [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
I'll use a wrapper for flexbox container, then spans became flex element and can be traited as you want.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  width:200px;/*not necessary*/
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#top-left{
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

#bottom-left,
#bottom-right{
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span id="top-left" class="is-text-align-right">$1.15</span>
<span id="bottom-left" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$2.00</span>
<span id="bottom-right" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$3.00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No need of multiple css for this simple requirement. just he need to add a break for first span

Comment: we don't know how the OP has the HTML so this is a possible solution

Answer (score -2):

add following css to your code

```css
#top-left::after{
        content: "\a";
        white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<span id="top-left" class="is-text-align-right">$1.15</span>
<span id="bottom-left" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$2.00</span>
<span id="bottom-right" class="is-display-inline-block is-text-align-right">$3.00</span>
```

if you required space between 2 and 3rd span. you can add this CSS also.

```
#bottom-right {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: there is no more explanation required for this question. here i mentioned he need to add small CSS to his code. Simple code is first preference for development

Comment: For example you can explain why you use /a and word-wrap